# Can a lady stipulate in the nikah contract that her husband may not enter into polygamy?

Tags: fiqh, nikah, women, contract

From what I understand, in Islam marriage is a contract. And conditions can be set in it breaking of which can be grounds for divorce.

Thus is it acceptable or considered makruh for a female to stipulate that her husband not marry another woman while married to her i.e **deny him to be polygamous**

Or would this make her a sinner as she is making something that is Halal for him to be impermissible?

Comment: Salam. A woman stipulating that in her marriage contract is not considered "making haram something that is halal", rather it's just requesting that he NOT do something. So it's perfectly valid.